# How can I check if my bluetooth module supports BLE capability in Linux

Tags: linux, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am wondering to know this because I have some BLE devices and want to check if I can play around it with my own desktop bluetooth module.

Comment: have you tried installing `bluez` or `bluez-utils` on your distribution. What's your distribution?

Comment: @IsaA it is Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install bluez and bluez-utils via apt-get. Then check if the ble device is detected with hciconfig

Comment: `hciconfig` is deprecated and no longer packaged in some distros.

Answer (score 10):

If hciconfig is installed Try getting the LE supported states using `sudo hciconfig hci0 lestates`

This should display possible LE specific status some thing like below

```
Supported link layer states:
        YES Non-connectable Advertising State
        YES Scannable Advertising State
        YES Connectable Advertising State
        YES Directed Advertising State
        YES Passive Scanning State
        YES Active Scanning State
        YES Initiating State/Connection State in Master Role
        YES Connection State in the Slave Role
        YES Non-connectable Advertising State and Passive Scanning State combination
        YES Scannable Advertising State and Passive Scanning State combination
        YES Connectable Advertising State and Passive Scanning State combination
        YES Directed Advertising State and Passive Scanning State combination
        YES Non-connectable Advertising State and Active Scanning State combination
        YES Scannable Advertising State and Active Scanning State combination
        YES Connectable Advertising State and Active Scanning State combination
        YES Directed Advertising State and Active Scanning State combination
        YES Non-connectable Advertising State and Initiating State combination
        YES Scannable Advertising State and Initiating State combination
        YES Non-connectable Advertising State and Master Role combination
        YES Scannable Advertising State and Master Role combination
        YES Non-connectable Advertising State and Slave Role combination
        YES Scannable Advertising State and Slave Role combination
        YES Passive Scanning State and Initiating State combination
        YES Active Scanning State and Initiating State combination
        YES Passive Scanning State and Master Role combination
        YES Active Scanning State and Master Role combination
```

Comment: `hciconfig` is deprecated and no longer packaged in some distros.